# how to display a userform on active workbook

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am new to vba language, and recently I have to write a Excel addIn to do some automatic work. My addIn has one userform, and users of my addIn may have multiple workbooks open at same time and switch between those workbooks, which require the opened userform stick to the active workbook.Bellow is my attempt:
*

```
Private WithEvents App As Application
Private m_userform1 As UserForm1
Private Sub App_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
       MsgBox Wb.Name
       Set m_userform = UserForms.Add("UserForm1")
       m_userform.Show vbModeless
End Sub
Private Sub App_WorkbookDeactivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox Wb.Name
    Unload m_userform
    Set m_userform = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    'MsgBox "test app_workbookOpen"
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "^e", "Commander"
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

With this implementation, when I open a workbook, everything runs ok, but then open another workbook, an error message 5 appears, which is thrown from

```
Set m_userform = UserForms.Add("UserForm1")
```

Can someone give me some insights into this problem? Many appreciates!

Comment: Can you show what the actual error message is? I suspect that you are attempting to add the userform again when it already exists

Comment: @Zac I think that will be `Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)`

Comment: @Zac, the error message is "Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)". And I think in the App_WorkbookDeactivate, the shown userform will be unloaded, so it doesn't matter call the show method again in App_WorkbookActivate.